# Как закрыть все окна при выходе из учетной записи firebase при использовании Obx в getX

Tags: flutter, dart

использую следующую логику при открытий приложения, которая проверяет авторизован ли пользователь:

```
class Root extends GetWidget<AuthController> {
  const Root({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(() {
      return controller.user != null ? NavBar() : AuthPage();
    });
  }
}
```

в Виджете `NavBar()` есть кнопка выхода, при нажатий которая, переходит в Экран с кнопками:

```
IconButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => FullDialog(),
              ),
            ),
            icon: Icon(Icons.logout),
          ),
```

на экране `FullDialog()` есть кнопка которая "разлогинивает" пользователя и не переходит назад(так задумано).

Вопрос, почему не срабатывает `Obx(()=>` до того как пользователь выходит из своей учетной записи и как это можно решить (то есть как при таком раскладе убрать наложенный спереди экран)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажи как объявлена переменная `user` в контроллере (это очень важный момент, значение должно иметь Rx-тип и изменяться в соответствии со своим типом). Еще, стоит пояснить по какой причине тут не используется навигация GetX (которая своими методами легко позволяет "закрывать" все экраны до нужного).

Comment: вот:
  Rxn<User> _firebaseUser = Rxn<User>();
  User? get user => _firebaseUser.value;

Comment: @yar85 даже если использовать Get.to суть не меняется

Comment: Тогда получается что выражение должно иметь вид `controller.user.value != null ? NavBar() : AuthPage()`... а присваивание этой переменной значения `null` -  `controller.user.value = null;` (это из виджета. Если присваивать в методе контроллера - то просто `user.value = null;`. Еще может работать такое: `user();`, потому что у Rxn-переменных есть метод установки значения, и вызов без аргумента нового значения равнозначен `user(null);`).

Comment: @yar85 вопрос не в том что он не правильно работает(а он правильно работает), а в том что не закрываются наложенный экран

Comment: _«даже если использовать Get.to суть не меняется»_ - я имел в виду использование методов типа `Get.offAllNamed`. Они вроде с тем же стековым навигатором первой версии работают (но требуют использования GetX-маршрутов), то есть закрытие всех экранов с ними выполняется проще. _«он правильно работает»_ - значит я понял вопрос неправильно, т.к. комменты касались именно _«не срабатывает Obx(()=>»_.

Comment: @yar85 спасибо, помогло

Comment: Если не затруднит - напиши самоответ, пожалуйста. А то я даже не понял в чем здесь основная проблема была, решив что она в реактивности :)